# Squib: Autonumbering cards

Tags: ruby, squib

Is there a feature in squib to be able to autonumber cards? For example, starting with

```
Squib::Deck.new(cards: 6) do
```

I could mark on the card that it is card #1, #2, etc, in the deck. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not necessarily a squib feature, but you can use a range to number the cards:

```
cards = 6
Squib::Deck.new(cards: cards) do
  text str: (1..cards)
end
```

Comment: As the dev behind Squib, this is how you do it.